# Get value from CSS through querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a specific value on CSS class through `querySelector` but still can't find a solution:

What I'm trying to get is the "40px" value:

```js
function onS(obj) {
  var logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
  var value = logo.style.marginLeft;
  alert(value);
}
```

```css
.logo { display: block; position: relative; margin-left: 40px; }
```

```html
<div class="logo" onmouseover="onS(this)">Test!</div>
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logo.style` just looks at the inline `style` attribute, it doesn't get the computed style.

To get CSS values from a `<style>` tag or external stylesheet, use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
function onS(obj) {
  var logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
  var value = window.getComputedStyle(logo).marginLeft;
  alert(value);
}
```

```css
.logo { display: block; position: relative; margin-left: 40px; }
```

```html
<div class="logo" onmouseover="onS(this)">Test!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used jQuery to get the value...

```js
function onS(obj) {
  var logo = $('.logo');
  var value = logo.css('marginLeft');
  alert(value);
}
```

```css
.logo { display: block; position: relative; margin-left: 40px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo" onmouseover="onS(this)">Test!</div>
```